# Remove rows based on duplicates in a single column in Google Sheets with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to remove all duplicates of row based on the second column data.

[SO OF THIS SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPD0M.jpg) row 7 and 8 would be removed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. In my case I have columns from A to F and rows from 1 to 30000.

Thank you.

I tried this code but the big one problem is that it ever use the first column and i dont know how to put it to do use the secont column T-T

`

```
`function removeDuplicates() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var newData = [];
    var ids = [];
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1');
    for (var i in data) {
      var row = data[0][1];
      var duplicate = false;
      if (ids.indexOf(row[0]) > -1) {
        duplicate = true;
      } else {
        duplicate = false;
        ids.push(row[0]);
      }
      if (!duplicate) {
        newData.push(row);
      }

}
sheet.clearContents();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData\[0\].length).setValues(newData);
}`
```

`

Comment: It looks like you copied this from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, [edit] to make sure you do **ALL** the following: 1.Include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, 2. Mention the author's name, and 3. [Quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Duplicate Rows based upon value in column2

```
function removeDupes() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let d = 0;
  let u = []
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (~u.indexOf(r[1])) {
      sh.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++)
    } else {
      u.push(r[1]);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: i have to assume, that you resolved a a big problem, you is a GOD!!

My hero, very tanks!!